# Elixir - GenServer with initial state of several other GenServer pids

Tags: elixir

I'm running into a deadlock problem with automatically starting up my supervision tree. The initial state of one GenServer are the children workers of another supervisor in the tree. Here's the code:

Supervisor and Workers:

```
defmodule Parallel.Worker.Supervisor do
  import Supervisor.Spec

  def start_link do
    # Start up a worker for each core
    schedulers = :erlang.system_info(:schedulers)
    children = Enum.map(1..schedulers,
      &(worker(Parallel.Worker.Server, [], id: "Parallel.Worker#{&1}")))

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Parallel.Worker.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  def workers do
     Process.whereis(Parallel.Supervisor)
      |> Supervisor.which_children
      |> Enum.reduce [], fn
        {_name, pid, :worker, _module}, acc -> [{make_ref, pid} | acc]
        _, acc -> acc
      end
  end

end
```

GenServer with state of those worker pids:

```
defmodule Parallel.Process.Server do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, workers: [Parallel.Worker.Supervisor.workers])
  end
end
```

As you can see on the last line, I am calling "Parallel.Worker.Supervisor.workers" which seems to block waiting on the tree to initialize which won't complete until this method returns. How can you have supervised PIDs as initial GenServer state?

UPDATE:

I wanted to not use poolboy (though it is a good suggestion to look at the source) to help me learn more. I'm not trying to make anything in particular, my worker simply processes a passed function with its arguments. Heres the worker GenServer:

```
defmodule Parallel.Worker do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state, [])
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  # Using cast to be async as the job could take longer than the default 5 seconds,
  # Don't want client blocked on waiting for job to complete
  def handle_cast({:execute, fun, args, return_pid, job_ref}, state) do
    Logger.debug fn()-> "#{inspect self}: Recevied job with args: #{inspect args} for job #{inspect job_ref} to return to #{inspect return_pid}" end
    send(return_pid, {job_ref, apply(fun, args), self})
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you need to rearchitecture the application without passing worker pids explicitly. What are you _really_ trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a pooling library such as Poolboy? Check this article: http://hashnuke.com/2013/10/03/managing-processes-with-poolboy-in-elixir.html

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you want to create some kind of a pool here? As mentioned in comments, you should look into poolboy. If for the sake of practice you want to implement this yourself, it's still worth looking into the poolboy code for inspiration.

In essence, a poolboy pool is managed by a "pool manager" - a gen_server that maintains a collection of known workers. This pool manager process internally starts a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor which is then used to start and supervise workers.

The pool manager process [during initialization first starts the supervisor](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy/blob/master/src/poolboy.erl#L129). Then, it calls `prepopulate/1` to [start supervised worker processes](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy/blob/master/src/poolboy.erl#L138). This function will dynamically create N workers [via supervisor:start_child/2](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy/blob/master/src/poolboy.erl#L255), and the pool manager can keep the list of worker pids internally.

This ensures that pool manager process doesn't need to talk to the parent supervisor during initialization (which is what's causing your deadlock). Instead, the manager creates children itself. Relying on an internal supervisor still ensures that workers reside in the supervision tree.

There are some other fine-print details needed to ensure that everything works properly. Poolboy process (pool manager) will trap exits, link to monitors, and also monitor workers when they are checked out. This ensures proper detection of worker crashes. I suggest reading the code for further analysis.

My opinion is that this can be an interesting exercise to gain better understanding of OTP. However, if you're doing this for production, you'll probably be better off using poolboy directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was really helpful in understanding the poolboy code. I'm doing it for learning purposes as you mentioned, to gain a better understanding of OTP.

Comment: Yeah, I suggest going in small steps. For start, you could just implement a pool manager which creates workers directly from it's init/1, without using supervisors. Once that works, you might introduce a simple_one_for_one to handle supervision. Then, you could start monitoring workers to find out when they crash. Finally, you might add "on-demand" creation on workers - processes which are created on demand, and terminated after the client does the work.